# How can I get the list of all users using the BuildFire Public API?

Tags: swagger, buildfire

I wanted to get the list of all users using the `BuildFire Public API`.

How can I do it? 
Also, I can't find the request in the **Swagger**.

Comment: Are you trying to access this form another server or from the plugin? If its from the plugin you can create a widget service that gathers a list of all your users. ref https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/BuildFire-Widget-Services

Comment: I'm trying to access from another server. How can I get the list of all users globally? Not for only plugin.

Comment: To my knowledge, there isn't a gateway API that does this.